# Information of new user won´t show in terminal

Tags: ubuntu, command-line, terminal, useradd

I created a new user and logged in successfully on my ubuntu 20.04 machine.

When I logged in as root the terminal looks like this:

`root@ubuntu-s-1vcpu-1gb-fra1-01:~#`

When I login with my "mynewuser" account I only see a `$`, nothing more. I want to display the same information as before:

`mynewuser@ubuntu-s-1vcpu-1gb-fra1-01:~`

This was how I created my new user:

```
mkdir -p /home/mynewuser/.ssh
touch /home/mynewuser/.ssh/authorized_keys
echo "publickey" > /home/mynewuser/.ssh/authorized_keys
useradd -d /home/mynewuser mynewuser
usermod -aG sudo mynewuser
chown -R mynewuser:mynewuser /home/mynewuser/
chmod 700 /home/mynewuser/.ssh
chmod 644 /home/mynewuser/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

Did I miss anything?

Comment: Yes, you missed a lot. When first creating a new user, let the `useradd` (or `adduser`, or whichever tool you use) set up the initial shell, directory tree, and so on, and copy the base system skeleton files to the new users home. *THEN* you can modify the files, add shh keys, and so on. Many of the basic tools will not create or modify an already existing directory (and/or the files/subdirectories in the directory), because that is safer than accidentally clobbering everything that is already there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you change the order of operations then it can be simplified somewhat:

```
useradd -m -s /bin/bash mynewuser
usermod -aG sudo mynewuser
su -u mynewuser - mkdir -m 700 .ssh
echo "...public key..." | su -u mynewuser - tee .ssh/authorized_keys
```

This should also mean that when you create the home directory the scripts from `/etc/skel` can get copied in correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I need the `-s` flag to display that:

`useradd -m -s $(which bash) -G sudo mynewuser`